# Dar formato a respuesta de una API en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, api

estoy utilizando una API REST en Javascript la cual me arroja los siguientes datos:
[image: Respuesta de la API]

El detalles que quiero hacer uso de **solamente una parte de la respuesta**, como por ejemplo *"bucket"*.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
req.post(
  {
    url: "https://api.salesup.com/login",
    form: formData
  },
  function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  console.log(err, body);//Aquí me arroja la respuesta en "body"
  //Aquí debería ir algo como
  //console.log(body.bucket);
  }
);
```

Tengo entendido que se debe dar formato, he investigado un poco y algunas veces usan algo parecido a `JSON.stringify(body)`

Espero puedan ayudarme ya que no tengo experiencia implementando APIs. **Gracias de antemano**

Comment: En lugar de la imagen coloca un ejemplo completo de la respuesta. Y parece que la respuesta es un arreglo entonces si hay más de un objeto con la propiedad bucket qué se hará?

Answer (score 0):

Podría transformar ese texto en formato JSON a un objeto JavaScript con la función JSON.parse()

```
req.post(
  {
    url: "https://api.salesup.com/login",
    form: formData
  },
  function(err, httpResponse, body) {
  const data = JSON.parse(body);
  console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Comment: Por favor, añade una explicación de la respuesta que das argumentando el porque debería funcionar. Y si te es posible incluso un enlace de referencia a documentación relacionada. Gracias